# How to combine two columns into one?

Tags: postgresql, update

I have a table in PostgreSQL 11 with two `varchar` columns like this:

```
 A | B  
---+---
 m | n 
 x | y
```

Now I want to add a column `C` which should contain the contents of `A` and `B` (`concat(A, B)`):

```
 A | B | C 
---+---+---
 m | n | mn
 x | y | xy
```

After that I want to drop `A` and `B` so that I effectively replace the two original columns.

How can I set the value of `C` to the concatenated values of `A` and `B`?

Comment: Do you care about future `insert`'s to `(a, b)`? In other words, what if you `insert into table (a, b) values ('a', 'b')`? Do you care about generating `c`?

Comment: No, I don't care about future insertions of `(a, b)`. These two columns should be dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have already the solution yourself:

```
UPDATE thetable SET c = CONCAT(a, b)
```

Comment: I tried it, but PostgreSQL refuses to execute it with the following message: "Unsafe query: 'Update' statement without 'where' updates all table rows at once"

Comment: It works! Seems like IntelliJ wanted to safe me from a dangerous `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: You can always add `WHERE TRUE` if needed...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I realize that you can't use this answer since it applies to PostgreSQL 12. Nevertheless, unless someone suggests I delete it, I intend to keep it since it answers your question, even though it requires a newer PostgreSQL version.

I suggest [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html).

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/262806/11153 answers your immediate question. However, it seems to me that a generated column provides a long-term solution, namely, per the docs:

> A stored generated column is computed when it is written (inserted or updated) and occupies storage as if it were a normal column.

```
$psql -U postgres
psql (12.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create table foo(
   a varchar, 
   b varchar, 
   c varchar GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a || b) STORED
);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into foo (a, b) values ('x', 'y');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into foo (a, b) values ('m', 'n');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from foo
postgres-# ;
 a | b | c  
---+---+----
 x | y | xy
 m | n | mn
(2 rows)

-- update a row
postgres=# update foo set a = 'b' where b = 'y';
UPDATE 1
postgres=# select * from foo;
 a | b | c  
---+---+----
 m | n | mn
 b | y | by
```